# Select employees with less than 10 leaves in a given date range

Tags: elasticsearch

I have a document with below structure

```
{
   id:1,
   leaves:[
            {
               "reason":"",
               "date":"2019-01-01"
            },
            {
               "reason":"",
               "date":"2019-04-30"
            }
          ]
}
```

leaves is a nested document. Document structure can be changed.
I need to select employees with less that 10 leaves in a given range -2019-01-01 to 2019-05-30.

I tried bucket selector aggregation but "min_bucket" bucket path was not pointing to empty buckets (needed where no leaves where present in range). I was getting below response and no records were returned.

```
  "max_hourly_inner" : {
              "value" : null,
              "keys" : [ ]
            }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I came up with the below query. Its a bit tricky when it comes to performing aggregations on nested, however you can achieve it via the following aggregations which I've used.

- [Terms Aggregation](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-aggregations-bucket-terms-aggregation.html)
- [Nested Aggregation](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-aggregations-bucket-terms-aggregation.html)
- [Date Range Aggregation](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-aggregations-bucket-daterange-aggregation.html)
- [Bucket Selector Aggregation](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-aggregations-pipeline-bucket-selector-aggregation.html)

The equation I'm solving is *show me the list of students with less than 2 leaves in specified date range* i.e. from `2019-04-01` to `2019-05-30`

### Sample Documents:

```
// This student has 3 leaves over all and all 3 leaves in the specified date 
POST myleaves/_doc/1
{
  "id": 1001,
  "leaves" : [
    {
      "reason" : "",
      "date" : "2019-04-01"
    },
    {
      "reason" : "",
      "date" : "2019-04-29"
    },
    {
      "reason" : "",
      "date" : "2019-04-30"
    }
  ]
}

//This student has 4 leaves out of which 2 are in specified date range
POST myleaves/_doc/2
{
  "id": 1002,
  "leaves" : [
    {
      "reason" : "",
      "date" : "2019-04-01"
    },
    {
      "reason" : "",
      "date" : "2019-04-04"
    },
    {
      "reason" : "",
      "date" : "2019-07-29"
    },
    {
      "reason" : "",
      "date" : "2019-07-30"
    }
  ]
}

// This student has one leave but no leaves in specified date range
POST myleaves/_doc/3
{
  "id": 1003,
  "leaves":[
    {
      "reason" : "",
      "date" : "2019-07-29"
    }
  ]
}

//This student has no leaves at all
POST myleaves/_doc/4
{
  "id": 1004,
  "leaves":[

    ]
}
```

Below is the structure of the aggregation query

```
- Terms Aggregation on `id` field
 - Nested Aggregation on `leaves` field
  - Date Range aggregation on `leaves.date` field
   - Bucket Selector Aggregation on `count`. This is the part where we specify our condition 
 - Bucket Selector Aggregation to retrieve only documents having one bucket. (To avoid showing bucket with 0 doc counts)
```

### Aggregation Query:

```
POST <your_index_name>/_search
{  
   "size":0,
   "aggs":{  
      "mystudents":{  
         "terms":{  
            "field":"id",
            "size":10
         },
         "aggs":{  
            "mycount":{  
               "nested":{  
                  "path":"leaves"
               },
               "aggs": {
                 "valid_dates": {
                   "date_range": {
                     "field": "leaves.date",
                     "ranges": [
                       {
                         "from": "2019-04-01",
                         "to": "2019-05-30"
                       }
                     ]
                   },
                   "aggs": {
                     "myselector": {
                       "bucket_selector": {
                         "buckets_path": {
                           "myparams": "_count"
                         },
                         "script": "params.myparams <= 2"    <---- You may have to change this for less than 10 leaves params.myparams <=10
                       }
                     }
                   }
                 }
               }
            },
            "mybucket_selector":{  
               "bucket_selector":{  
                  "buckets_path":{  
                     "my_bucket_count":"mycount>valid_dates._bucket_count"
                  },
                  "script":"params.my_bucket_count == 1"
               }
            }
         }
      }
   }
}
```

Note the comment I've mentioned in the aggregation query.

### Aggregation Response:

```
{
  "took" : 2,
  "timed_out" : false,
  "_shards" : {
    "total" : 1,
    "successful" : 1,
    "skipped" : 0,
    "failed" : 0
  },
  "hits" : {
    "total" : {
      "value" : 4,
      "relation" : "eq"
    },
    "max_score" : null,
    "hits" : [ ]
  },
  "aggregations" : {
    "mystudents" : {
      "doc_count_error_upper_bound" : 0,
      "sum_other_doc_count" : 0,
      "buckets" : [
        {
          "key" : 1002,
          "doc_count" : 1,
          "mycount" : {
            "doc_count" : 4,                                 <----- Total Count of Leaves 
            "valid_dates" : {
              "buckets" : [
                {
                  "key" : "2019-04-01T00:00:00.000Z-2019-05-30T00:00:00.000Z",
                  "from" : 1.5540768E12,
                  "from_as_string" : "2019-04-01T00:00:00.000Z",
                  "to" : 1.5591744E12,
                  "to_as_string" : "2019-05-30T00:00:00.000Z",
                  "doc_count" : 2                            <------ Count of leaves in specified range
                }
              ]
            }
          }
        },
        {
          "key" : 1003,
          "doc_count" : 1,
          "mycount" : {
            "doc_count" : 1,
            "valid_dates" : {
              "buckets" : [
                {
                  "key" : "2019-04-01T00:00:00.000Z-2019-05-30T00:00:00.000Z",
                  "from" : 1.5540768E12,
                  "from_as_string" : "2019-04-01T00:00:00.000Z",
                  "to" : 1.5591744E12,
                  "to_as_string" : "2019-05-30T00:00:00.000Z",
                  "doc_count" : 0
                }
              ]
            }
          }
        },
        {
          "key" : 1004,
          "doc_count" : 1,
          "mycount" : {
            "doc_count" : 0,
            "valid_dates" : {
              "buckets" : [
                {
                  "key" : "2019-04-01T00:00:00.000Z-2019-05-30T00:00:00.000Z",
                  "from" : 1.5540768E12,
                  "from_as_string" : "2019-04-01T00:00:00.000Z",
                  "to" : 1.5591744E12,
                  "to_as_string" : "2019-05-30T00:00:00.000Z",
                  "doc_count" : 0
                }
              ]
            }
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

If you look at the response,

- `1001` ***didn't appear*** as he had more than 2 leaves in specified date range,
- `1002` **appears** because he had exactly 2 leaves out of 4 leaves he has taken in specified date range
- `1003` and `1004` **appears** as they have not taken any leaves in the specified range.

Clause is select students with less than 2 leaves (including students who has not taken any leaves) in specified date range.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks for the answer. @Kamal can you suggest any open source applications(source code available) which use elastic search NEST so that I can learn best practices for building queries